# Bad interaction between babel and xypic?

Tags: babel, xy-pic

I'm writing an elaborate in Italian, and I'm using [`XY-pic`](http://xy-pic.sourceforge.net/) to draw some diagrams.
Unfortunately it seems that `babel` is interacting with `XY-pic`, making it impossible to group elements.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix @R=1pt{
a & \mathbb{N} & \Rightarrow & \mathbb{N} & e & f & g \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 
\save "1,2"."2,4"*[F.]\frm{} \restore
}

\end{document}
```

Which outputs:

[image]

While this is the expected output:

[image]

Which is the output I get removing the `\usepackage[italian]{babel}` line.

Is there anyway to use both `babel` and `xy-pic` *and* avoiding this interaction between the two?

Comment: `\shorthandoff{"}` before the matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need `babel` shorthands during your document, just issue

```
\AtBeginDocument{\shorthandoff{"}}
```

after loading `babel`. Otherwise, you have to modify the `\xymatrix` command so that it performs `\shorthandoff{"}` before starting the matrix and undoes it at the end.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\let\ORIGxymatrix\xymatrix
\def\xymatrix#1#{\begingroup\shorthandoff{"}\INNERxymatrix{#1}}
\def\INNERxymatrix#1#2{\ORIGxymatrix#1{#2}\endgroup}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix @R=1pt{
a & \mathbb{N} & \Rightarrow & \mathbb{N} & e & f & g \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7
\save "1,2"."2,4"*[F.]\frm{} \restore
}

"" % this should print opening double quotes (just to see that shorthands work again

\end{document}
```

[image]