# Why is Babel intefering with xypic here?

Tags: babel, xy-pic

This file runs fine if I comment out the usepackage brazil line.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{xy}
\input xy 
\begin{document}
\[\xy  ,(0,0)="A" \endxy   \]
\end{document}
```

But if I do not comment it out I get an error message and no pdf:

```
! Paragraph ended before saveid@COORDi was complete
<to be read again>
```

Can someone tell me why it is happening?

I need to have the babel brazil, and I hope I can use my actual (much longer, of course) xypic with no major changes.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133562/bad-interaction-between-babel-and-xypic help?

Comment: Yes. That solves it for me.